# jQuery update - access denied

Tags: 7, installation

Trying to setup the latest [jquery update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) dev version, needed for the installation of the amazing [social_count](http://drupal.org/project/social_count) mobile-friendly count widget, I can't configure the module. When logging as user #1 and going to http://www.example.com/admin/config/development/jquery_update, 
all I get is access denied. I tried 'drush cc all' to clear the cache but in vain. Any ideas?

Comment: Note - this is an admin user and it has the 'administer site configuration' pemission needed by hook_menu of the jquery_update module

Comment: As a bypass, I've added the needed version manually into jquery_update.module:

$version = variable_get('jquery_update_jquery_version', '1.7');

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Update doesn't implement hook_menu but instead uses form_alter with [jquery_update_form_system_performance_settings_alter](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/jquery_update_form_system_performance_settings_alter/7)

You can find the configuration options at `admin/config/development/performance`.

Comment: No, the configuration option is not there.

Comment: Still unresolved

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error today after upgrading jquery_update to version 7.x-4.0-alpha1.

I gained access by navigating to `/admin/people/permissions` and granting "Administer jQuery Update" permission to Administrators.

I realise that the question is nine years old, but for anyone encountering the issue today, the lack of this permission may be the cause.